# Function being called multiple times in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Excuse the title, didn't know how to describe it really, as I'm not sure what's happening:

**http://jsfiddle.net/KpmyR/7/**

If you look at that JS fiddle, I am attempting to create my own nudging control to understand how plugins work. My plugin is called by `$("#textbox1").DTJS()`

With one item on the page, my plugin seems to work ok, when I add multiple instances of it to the page, the code appears to be firing exponentially. (I'm basically waiting for a onClick event in my plugin).

As it is at the moment, I have called my `$("#textbox1").DTJS()` Three times like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#textbox1").DTJS({
    'width': '75px',
    'max': '15',
    'min': '5'
});

$("#textbox2").DTJS({
    'width': '75px',
    'max': '15',
    'min': '5'
});


$("#textbox3").DTJS({
    'width': '75px',
    'max': '15',
    'min': '5'
});
});
```

If I click on the bottom one, it increments/deincremements by 1, if I click the middle it does it by 2, and if I click the top one it does it by 3.

Could someone please outline why this is happening?

Comment: check this fiddle working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KpmyR/8/

Comment: This is really no way to write a proper plugin, you should be doing something a lot more like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KpmyR/10/) !!

Comment: @adeneo It does look neater like that I must admit. Plus I assume that doing the return each on line 18 is for chaining? So everything I wanted each individual instance to do would be in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change this:

```
$('.valueUp').click(...);
```

to this:

```
$(this).siblings('.valueUp').click(...);
```

The same is true for `.valueDown`.

By binding an event to just `.valueUp`, you are binding it to any `.valueUp` on the page, which explains why the event gets bound 3 times on the first one and 2 times on the second one.

---

**A couple of other tips:**

- `this` is already a jQuery object

  As Snuffleupagus pointed out, `this` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to call `$(this)`. This is true for any function you add to `$.fn`.
- return `this`

  By returning `this` at the end of the plugin, you maintain chainability. For example, if you add `return this` to the end of your plugin, you could do something like this:

  $("#textbox1").DTJS({'width':'75px', 'max':'15', 'min':'5'}).fadeIn();

Comment: This works nicely. Would you mind explaining why this is? I'm doing this for learning purposes rather than production. I obviously assumed that it would effectively do this : `click -> this instance that was clicked"` rather than `click -> act as if all were clicked`

Comment: when you say `$('.valueUp').click(...)`, you are binding a click event to all elements with a class of `valueUp` on the page. The first time you call your plugin, there is only one on the page. The second time, there are two, and the first one gets the event bound twice. The third time, there are three, so the first one now has that event bound 3 times. Your click handler will be called once for every time it is bound.

Comment: by saying `$(this).siblings('.valueUp').click(...)`, you are making it relative to the element you called the plugin on. In other words, you only bind the click event to the `.valueUp` that is a sibling of the current textbox. That way, the event only gets bound once and therefore only fires once.

Comment: And to comment on your assumption ("`click -> act as if all were clicked`"): its not acting as if all were clicked. It knows which one was clicked, but it just has multiple handlers bound to it, and it runs them all.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense really. Oddly I've never had an issue with this before, but I can see that in plugin-land, I am effectively creating handlers each time the plugin is called - Oh dear. At least I found out now rather than later! :)

Comment: fyi you don't need run `this` through `$()`, it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus +1 good call -- forgot about that. For other readers: in plugins, `this` is already a jQuery object, whereas in event handlers, `this` is a DOM element.

Comment: I like the chaining idea, however wouldn't this just return the textbox and not the appended/prepended items? e.g. If I use  .fadeOut() at the end, It fades out the textbox but the up/down are still there.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper right -- it just returns what you invoked the plugin on. So, you could do `$("#textbox1").DTJS(...).closest('.nudgerContainer').fadeOut()` or you could just return `this.closest('.nudgerContainer')`. I'd advocate for the former.

Answer (score 3):

You're applying your events via a class, so each time you call your plugin you're binding another event to all instances of `.valueUp` and `.valueDown`.

Consider keeping a copy when you create your buttons and binding the events from your stored copy. (If you're selecting the same element multiple times in the same scope you're better off storing it in memory.)

e.g.,

```
var up = $('<button class="valueUp valueHoldDown btn-mini btn-primary' + settings.btnClass + '">-></button>');
this.after(up);
up.click(function(){ 
    // code 
});
```

Also note that when jQuery calls a function from `jQuery.fn`, `this` refers to the jQuery object rather than raw elements so you don't need to do `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you are having is with the click event handler:

```
$(".valueUp").click( function() {...})
```

The selector that is used in this line selects all elements with a class of valueUp. However as you add more nudge controls to the page, the event handler is run for each button on the page - resulting in the value being nudged by as many as there are controls on the page.

There are a couple of options:

Change the selector to be id based to a unique id, or change the selector so that it is relative to the input control itself.

Here is a working example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfp8a/